# Targeting and inserting an exact field with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Trying to insert a value into a specific field. Trying MySQL query such as this at the moment;

```
INSERT INTO tablename  (*column-name-col2+*)
VALUES 500
WHERE (idcolumn) = X
```

Anyone suggestions?

Current table layout:

```
IDCol  |  username1  |  username2 |  username3  | etc

1

2

3

4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` to add to an already created row in the table, so your code,I think,  should be

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnName='500' WHERE IDCol='X'
```

Comment: @cbarlow123 if it works then upvote it and select it otherwise wate for better answer